# Plug-in to set desktop wallpaper in OS X

Tags: macos, osx-lion

What I would like to create is a custom service that would set the desktop wallpaper image in OS X. It would pull the wallpaper image from an online service and set it as the desktop. I have searched all over the Apple documentation to see if there was a way to add such a service to OS X but haven't come up with anything.

I would like to make the service tie into OS X like iPhoto does.

[image: OSX Desktop Pref Pane]

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably overkill, but there is a service that sets a *screensaver* as the desktop wallpaper, so if you want to write a 0FPS screensaver this might do the trick:

http://www.wallsaverapp.com

I would also suggest searching around for tips involving Quartz Composer, as that is an Apple tool often used to plug into system services such as screensavers, iTunes visualizers, etc.

Comment: I was more looking for some kind of hook into the wallpaper pref panel. That way I can write a programe will do what I want.